# Unable to separate certain fields from each container of ingredients

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, web-scraping

I'm trying to separate three 3 fields, as in `name`,`unit`, and `measure` out of some ingredient containers from a [webpage](https://www.delicious.com.au/recipes/gnocchi-walnut-rosemary-pecorino-pesto/1b0defa9-53c8-4e9c-8c93-fb96a5348b31?r=recipes/gallery/opvo6a3l). I used BeautifulSoup to parse the ingredient containers and then re module to separate `unit` and `measure`. This is [the portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5N53.jpg) in that site I'm interested in grabbing the three fields from.

This is how I've tried so far:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.delicious.com.au/recipes/gnocchi-walnut-rosemary-pecorino-pesto/1b0defa9-53c8-4e9c-8c93-fb96a5348b31?r=recipes/gallery/opvo6a3l'

def get_content(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("ul.ingredient > li"):
        ingr_container = item.get_text(strip=True)
        ingr_unit_container = re.search(r"[\d.⁄a-z]+",ingr_container).group(0)
        ingr_name = re.sub(ingr_unit_container,"",ingr_container).strip()
        ingr_unit = re.sub(r"[a-z]+","",ingr_unit_container).strip()
        ingr_measure = re.sub(r"[\d.⁄]+","",ingr_unit_container).strip()
        yield ingr_name,ingr_unit,ingr_measure

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_content(s,link):
            print(item)
```

Ingredient containers are like:

```
500g potato gnocchi
2 tbs extra virgin olive oil
Finely grated zest and juice of 1 lemon
1⁄2 bunch basil, leaves picked
1 tbs finely chopped rosemary, plus fried rosemary leaves to serve
2 garlic cloves, crushed
50g grated pecorino, (or parmesan) plus extra to serve
50g roasted and chopped walnuts, plus extra to serve
100ml extra virgin olive oil
```

Current output the script produces from the above containers:

```
('potato gnocchi', '500', 'g')
('tbs extra virgin olive oil', '2', '')
('F grated zest and juice of 1 lemon', '', 'inely')
('bunch basil, leaves picked', '1⁄2', '')
('tbs finely chopped rosemary, plus fried rosemary leaves to serve', '1', '')
('garlic cloves, crushed', '2', '')
('grated pecorino, (or parmesan) plus extra to serve', '50', 'g')
('roasted and chopped walnuts, plus extra to serve', '50', 'g')
('extra virgin olive oil', '100', 'ml')
```

Expected output:

```
('potato gnocchi', '500', 'g')
('extra virgin olive oil', '2', 'tbs')
('Finely grated zest and juice of', '1', 'lemon')
('basil, leaves picked', '1⁄2', 'bunch')
('finely chopped rosemary, plus fried rosemary leaves to serve', '1', 'tbs')
('cloves, crushed', '2', 'garlic')
('grated pecorino, (or parmesan) plus extra to serve', '50', 'g')
('roasted and chopped walnuts, plus extra to serve', '50', 'g')
('extra virgin olive oil', '100', 'ml')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm nowhere close to good at regex. However, I find the following implementation working:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.delicious.com.au/recipes/gnocchi-walnut-rosemary-pecorino-pesto/1b0defa9-53c8-4e9c-8c93-fb96a5348b31?r=recipes/gallery/opvo6a3l'

def get_content(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("ul.ingredient > li"):
        ingr_container = item.get_text(strip=True)
        unit_container = re.search(r'[\d.⁄]+\s*?[a-zA-Z]+\s*?',ingr_container).group(0)
        ingr_name = ingr_container.replace(unit_container,"").strip()
        ingr_unit = re.search(r'[\d.⁄]+',unit_container).group(0)
        ingr_measure = unit_container.replace(ingr_unit,"").strip()
        yield ingr_name,ingr_unit,ingr_measure

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_content(s,link):
            print(item)
```

Output:

```
('potato gnocchi', '500', 'g')
('extra virgin olive oil', '2', 'tbs')
('Finely grated zest and juice of', '1', 'lemon')
('basil, leaves picked', '1⁄2', 'bunch')
('finely chopped rosemary, plus fried rosemary leaves to serve', '1', 'tbs')
('cloves, crushed', '2', 'garlic')
('grated pecorino, (or parmesan) plus extra to serve', '50', 'g')
('roasted and chopped walnuts, plus extra to serve', '50', 'g')
('extra virgin olive oil', '100', 'ml')
```

Answer (score 1):

So one solution could be to search for digits inside the text, which is the measure. It becomes a bit tricky, because sometimes the unit is part of the measure, sometimes there is an emtpy space between. But you can catch this up with conditions (there might be a regex-solution, too):

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.delicious.com.au/recipes/gnocchi-walnut-rosemary-pecorino-pesto/1b0defa9-53c8-4e9c-8c93-fb96a5348b31?r=recipes/gallery/opvo6a3l'

def get_content(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("ul.ingredient > li"):
        ingr_container = item.get_text(strip=True).split()

        for index, string in enumerate(ingr_container):
            if re.search(r'\d', string): #check for digits, or parts, that contain digits
                if not string.isdecimal(): #check if digits and characters are mixed
                    if not string.isalnum(): #check if it's a "backslash"-unit (e.g. 1/2)
                        ingr_measure = string
                        ingr_unit = ingr_container[index+1]     
                        to_remove = [index, index+1] #at this index (indices) the unit and measure is set   
                        break           

                    else: #split digit and characters
                        for i, char in enumerate(string):
                            if char.isalpha():
                                ingr_measure = string[:i]
                                ingr_unit = string[i:]
                                to_remove = [index, index]  
                                break
                        break
                else:
                    ingr_measure = string
                    ingr_unit = ingr_container[index+1]
                    to_remove = [index, index+1]
                    break

        ingr_name = ' '.join(ingr_container[:to_remove[0]] + ingr_container[to_remove[1]+1:]) #ingr_name is the whole ingr_container without measure and unit

        yield ingr_name, ingr_measure, ingr_unit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_content(s,link):
            print(item)
```

output:

```
('potato gnocchi', '500', 'g')
('extra virgin olive oil', '2', 'tbs')
('Finely grated zest and juice of', '1', 'lemon')
('basil, leaves picked', '1⁄2', 'bunch')
('finely chopped rosemary, plus fried rosemary leaves to serve', '1', 'tbs')
('cloves, crushed', '2', 'garlic')
('grated pecorino, (or parmesan) plus extra to serve', '50', 'g')
('roasted and chopped walnuts, plus extra to serve', '50', 'g')
('extra virgin olive oil', '100', 'ml')
```